# How did the term "to favor" come to signify a limp?

Tags: idioms

Often in athletics, horse racing and when you encounter a person with an injured limb or other thing it will be said "He seems to be favoring his right leg" by which a person/commentator/etc means "He seems to be having trouble with his right leg". This seems counter to the typical meaning of "to favor" which would mean "to show preference towards" in fact an injured leg often means preferring the other leg.

How did this meaning come about?

Comment: If you have two employees doing the same job and you favor one, then you put more unpleasant work on the other one. That's what someone with a painful leg does; they favor the painful leg by putting more work onto the other leg.

Comment: Not wishing to seem like a smartass, I think the explanation as given by John is so blindingly obvious the question itself is General Reference.

Comment: It's a metaphor. Most blindingly obvious things are metaphors. But we grow up with them, and others don't.

Comment: @Bradd Szonye: If you [look at the longer term](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I+favoured+my%2CI+favored+my&year_start=1820&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) I think the usage has been around a ***long*** time. If there's a UK/US difference in prevalence today, it's probably because it's become somewhat more dated/archaic in the UK these days, making it more likely to arise with the American spelling where it's still used fairly often.

Comment: @John: Is it "metaphoric" to say you "favoured" me with a reply there? Etymonline says the [indulge, treat with partiality](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=favor&allowed_in_frame=0) meanings date from C14. And 1500 years before that, *Latin favorem (nominative favor) "good will, inclination, partiality, support," coined by Cicero from stem of favere "to show kindness to"*. I think we *literally* favour people (and gammy legs) with indulgences and preferential treatments.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - It wasn't that obvious to me and I kind of agree with John that it's a metaphor much effortlessly understood by the native speakers.

Comment: @FumbleFingers As a native English speaker, I'm well aware of the expression - but (not being a racing or athletics fan) I've always assumed that it means the opposite of what it apparently does mean!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The OED has this use of the verb *favour* dating back to the 16th century:

> 7. To deal gently with; to avoid overtasking (a limb); to ease, save, spare. Now *colloq*. (esp. in stable parlance) and *dial*.
>
> 1526   W. Bonde *Pylgrimage of Perfection* iii. sig. YYYiiiiv,   Fauour thy body.
>
> 1590   R. Harvey *Plaine Percevall* sig. C4v,   A Preacher..must haue his reader at his elbow, to fauor his voice.
>
> 1607   G. Markham *Cavelarice* ii. 42   When a horse doth stand but firme vpon..three feete..fauoring the other.

Earlier senses are: to regard with favour; look kindly upon; to treat kindly; to treat with partiality; to aid or support.

Comment: +1: I figured the OED would have early citations like this. Thanks for providing them! So the usage doesn't go all the way back to the 14th C., but it does go almost to Middle English.

Comment: The usage may well go that far back, but the known record does not (yet) :)

Comment: Good point! Also, I found the 1590 citation especially interesting.

Answer (score 4):

In that context, [*favor*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/favor) has the meaning “treat with care”; stated that way, the connection to other senses of the word is more obvious.

This usage it appears at least as early as 1826 in [Robert Drury's Journal](http://books.google.com/books?id=hm8DAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA208&dq=%22I%20favoured%20my%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=2VaUUeaFNKO0iQKMrIGoCA&ved=0CDQQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22I%20favoured%20my%22&f=false):

> I walked on this seventh day; and though I favored my lame foot as much as I could, yet I rested but once all day. This way happened to be plain and easy.

However, this is the fourth edition of a book first published in 1729, so the usage may be considerably older, potentially predating Modern English. *Favor* [first saw use as a verb](http://etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=favor&searchmode=none) in the mid-14th Century.

Comment: Downvoter: I realize that this isn't my best answer ever, so if you have constructive criticism I'd appreciate it.

Comment: @ Bradd: The downvoter isn't me, but maybe it was cast when my earlier comment was valid. Whatever - "best answer ever" or not, I'll delete that comment, because it no longer applies.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thanks – and thanks again for helping to improve the answer.